Symmetry of Zeros of the Completed $L$-function $\xi_L(s)$
I am reading the paper A method for verifying the generalized Riemann hypothesis by Ghaith A. Hiary, Summer Ireland, and Megan Kyi. On page 8, the authors define the completed (L)-function:
$
\xi_L(s) := \epsilon N^{s/2} \pi^{-sr/2} \prod_{j=1}^r \Gamma\left(\frac{s}{2} + \frac{M_j}{2}\right) L(s),
$
where $ \epsilon $ is a complex number of modulus 1, $ M_j $ $(1 \leq j \leq r$) are real non-negative numbers, and $N$ is a positive constant. The function $\xi_L(s)$ extends to an entire function and satisfies the functional equation:
$
\xi_L(s) = \overline{\xi_L(1 - \overline{s})}.
$
I understand that this functional equation, combined with the fact that $\xi_L(s)$ is entire, implies that any non-simple zero not on the critical line $\Re(s) = 1/2$ will exhibit 4-fold symmetry. However, I am unclear on the precise reasoning behind this symmetry.
Why does the functional equation $\xi_L(s) = \overline{\xi_L(1 - \overline{s})}$, along with the properties of $\xi_L(s)$, lead to this 4-fold symmetry for such zeros?
Thank you in advance for your help!

Assume that $\rho=\beta+i\gamma$ is a zero of $\xi_L$. As explained in the paper, this implies that $0\leq\beta\leq 1$ and $\rho\not\in\{0,1\}$. Therefore, $L(\rho)=0$. Now it is assumed in the paper that $L(\overline{s})=\overline{L(s)}$, whence also $L(\overline{\rho})=0$. This implies that $\xi(\overline{\rho})=0$ as well. Finally, using the functional equation $\xi_L(s) = \overline{\xi_L(1 - \overline{s})}$, we make the deductions
\begin{align*}
\xi(\rho)=0&\quad \Longrightarrow\quad \xi(1-\overline{\rho})=0,\\
\xi(\overline{\rho})=0&\quad \Longrightarrow\quad \xi(1-\rho)=0.
\end{align*}
To sum up, if $\rho$ is a zero of $\xi_L$, then $\overline{\rho}$, $1-\rho$, $1-\overline{\rho}$ are also zeros of $\xi_L$.
Note that if $\rho$ is not real and does not lie on the critical line, then the indicated four points $\rho$, $\overline{\rho}$, $1-\rho$, $1-\overline{\rho}$ are distinct (and symmetric about the real axis and the critical line). It is also straightforward to show that the order of vanishing of $\xi_L$ is the same at the indicated four points.

On the other hand, the analogue of RH would lead to a symmetry group isomorphic to $Z/2Z$.
